# What is the way of clicking on links which could not be scrolled into view by Selenium + Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, href, webscarab

This is piece if my code:

```
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a""")
x.click()
```

But, this error are occurred:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a href="/p/BgEcF34Fqf6/?tagged=fast"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Hi! How is going?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try JavaScript click:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement


def javascript_click(self, locator):
    element = None
    if isinstance(locator, str):
        element = self.find_element(locator)
    elif isinstance(locator, WebElement):
        element = locator

    if element is not None:
        self._driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not click on locator " + element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code which was worked carefully:

```
#Scroll down the page to load more posts
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(10)
    j=j+1
```

Note that, you can generalize this scrolling into more that one reputation by use of for syntax.